# How to write data to textfile using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, activexobject, fso

I have some problem to write date to a file Test.txt by using JavaScript. I have find answer in good too but I am still can't solve it. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

```
function WriteFile(){
       var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
       var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("Test.txt", 8,true);
       x=document.getElementById("name").value;
       fh.WriteLine(x);
       fh.Close();
}
```

And

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="write" onclick="WriteFile()"/>
</form>
```

I think it's should be run well by I the simple example I see from ebook.

I am not sure with path of Test.txt. I put it in the same forder in my localhost.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the 8 for? Just use 
    `var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Test.txt",true);`

Comment: @danleyb2 , var FileObject = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Test.txt", 8, true); // 8=append, true=create if not exist

Answer (score 1):

This the example you could go through:-

```css
function WriteToFile(passForm) {
 
    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
    set s   = fso.CreateTextFile("<your Path>/filename.txt", True);
 
    var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstName');
    var lastName  = document.getElementById('lastName');
 
    s.writeline("First Name :" + FirstName);
    s.writeline("Last Name :" + lastName);
 
    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
```

```html
<form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
<label>Type your first name:</label>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstName" size="20">
 
<label>Type your last name: </abel>
<input type="text" name="LastName" id="lastName" size="20">
 
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8(v=vs.84).aspx it looks like you need to specify the full path for your file.

E.g. `"C:\\Test.txt"`

Update:

Just tested this in IE9 and it works.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Test.txt", 8, true);
    fh.WriteLine("foo");
    fh.Close();
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks!I have test with path like this already, but still not get result.

Comment: I don't know why? I am still not get result from it. I think have something to config at any thing else ? I am test it in IE8, IE9 and IE10 on win8 but still the same result

Comment: Are you running from an .HTA or other non-browser scripting? It will not work instead of a regular .HTML file due to security restrictions.