# How to save text values from web page locally and is it possible to have web page front end, C# back end?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, web

I am creating a web page that will have many text input boxes structured like the below example.

```
<input type="text" id="textID" name="textName" placeholder="Enter your text here">
```

I will have a button at the bottom of the page that I want to grab all the values from each text box, preferably if possible Serialize into XML format and then save locally. If Serializing is not possible, saving to a txt/doc/etc will work. I am using javascript to do that work.

I have figured out how to have my button when clicked save a document of my choosing locally, but I have to use a web url to pull from and this only saves the page source code. That does me no good. I cannot figure out what to put in place of the below save.href. The save.href is forcing the use of the URL which I do not want.

```
<HTML>
//web page stuff

//Many of these inputs like this one below
<input type="text" id="textID" name="textName" placeholder="Enter your text here">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function SaveData() 
{
  var fileURL = "http://localhost:51088/index.html";
  var fileName = "test.txt";


  if (!window.ActiveXObject) 
  {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = fileURL;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
  }

    // for IE
  else if (!!window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand) 
  {
    var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    _window.document.close();
    _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
    _window.close();
 }
}
</script>
</HTML>
```

This code above is producing a text file that downloads locally to my box but it is only of the page source code for the URL I provided. How can I grab all the values from the text boxes and save that data locally?

I know I can do something like this example below to grab the text box values but how can I then take this value and save it?

```
var textBoxValue = document.getElementById("textID").value;
```

And an additional path I ultimately would like to take is to somehow write a C# business layer code that can bind directly to the text boxes on the web page. If not bind, at least pass the values to the C# code. If I can achieve that then I can handle formatting, saving, etc within C#. Is it possible to have an HTML web page, with JavaScript as the UI and C# as the back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure out how to grab the values from each text box and save them to a text file. Code sample below does it. Now to research how to put this in XML format.

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInputId").value;

var fileURL = 'data:application/notepad;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(userInput);
var fileName = "test.txt";


if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
  var save = document.createElement('a');
  save.href = fileURL;

  save.target = '_blank';
  save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

  var event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent('click', true, true);
  save.dispatchEvent(event);
  (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}

// for IE
else if (!!window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand) {
  var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
  _window.document.close();
  _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
  _window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have an HTML web page, with JavaScript as the UI and C# as the back end?

Yes it is possible, using a website project or even a web application project from visual studio at least.

Additionally, the answer at [How to write data to textfile using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262356/how-to-write-data-to-textfile-using-javascript) may be what you are looking for to troubleshoot the saving text box values to a text file.

Comment: Do you have a link to point me to some resources on how to make use HTML as the UI and C# as back end? Also, I checked out the link to writing the text file but that did not work out.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? It's very brief, but explains the point and how to. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243156(v=vs.100)